# Debugging SSIS Script Component - Breakpoint is enabled but it does not hit

Tags: c#, debugging, ssis, breakpoints

I am working on a SSIS package that has some script components (in C#) inside data flow.

I used break points all the time with it and worked fine without any issue.

But yesterday suddenly it stopped working without throwing any errors or any.
The script works fine without breaking or any error, giving me the expected results as well but does not stop on break points.

I didn't change any visual studio configurations or project configuration.

Google and tried all the solutions others provided.

Clear all cache and all debug objects, rebuild the solution again, restart the machine as well but none of those worked.

Does anyone have this kind of experience?

Environment: Windows 10 Pro, VS 2017

Comment: Updated Visual Studio to the latest version, but was same..

Comment: Compare with a n older version but was unable to find any clue that causes this..

Comment: Do you use $ sign in any expression? When using $ sign debugger will not get a hit either :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last found the reason for the issue, the reason is that I used a conditional access operator inside the script.
The compiler compiles the code properly and works fine but the debugger somehow doesn't understand that operator and crashes.
Seems like SSDT use old C# version on debugging..

Answer (score 2):

Beware that if you're using a newer version of Visual Studio than what the SSIS package was created with, you need to avoid C# syntax that the compiler won't understand.  If you don't, your breakpoints won't be hit.

For example, I opened a package created in Visual Studio 2015 with Visual Studio 2017.  I used the newer "$" string interpolation instead of string.Format() and that caused the debugger to not hit any break points.  Reverting the string interpolation back to string.Format() got the debugger working again.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.
Spent half a day on this, should have checked my notes, because I found this and solved it before, at least for me.

Upgraded to the latest VS2017 and SSDT as of today, no help. Finally created a simple package with just a dataflow that had a csv source, and script transformation component, and a recordset destination.  Set a breakpoint in the script component, and it worked.

Compared project properties with my "real" project and found that Configuration Properties | Debugging | InteractiveMode was False; it was True in the test project. Set it to True in the real project, and the breakpoint worked.

I had forgotten that I set it False to test package error handling.